# Catching the same expection in every method of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I, a beginner, am working on a simple card-based GUI. written in Python. There is a base class that, among other things, consists a vocabulary of all the cards, like `_cards = {'card1_ID': card1, 'card2_ID': card2}`. The cards on the GUI are referenced by their unique IDs.

As I plan to make the code avabile for other beginners, I want to explicitly inform them if they gave a card ID that does not exists (instead of throwing a KeyError). Now I have a ton of repetitive try-expect clause that makes me suspicious:

*Part of the code, one-line methods without try-catching:*

```
def shift(self, card_ID, amount):
        """Moves the card by the given amount of pixels.
            :param amount: the horizontal and vertical amount of shifting in pixels; tuple"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].shift(amount)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")


    def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
        """Aligns the card to the given position."""

        try:
            card = self._cards[card_ID]
            card.align(horizontal, vertical)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID") 


    def invert(self, card_ID):
        """Inverts the card's colour"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].invert()
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")
```

**Is this an accepted practice? Are there any better way to catch this KeyError in every method of the class?**

Comment: Consider a [decorator](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)

Comment: An other approach will be overwrite \__getitem\__ of _cards instance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an object for your cards collection that raises a `KeyError` when what you want is a `ValueError`? Or alternatively, why do you want a `ValueError` in the first place? Why not just catch a `KeyError` rather than a `ValueError` at the place in your code that is making use of your class? If the issue is the custom error message, probably the best thing to do is create your own `CardsCollection` type with its own error message built-in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extract the actual getting of the card from the id into a separate method, with a try/except there, and call that method from everywhere else.

```
def get_card(self, card_id):
    try:
        return self._cards[card_ID]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")

def invert(self, card_id):
    return self.get_card(card_id).invert()

...
```

Comment: I would have named the method `get_card()` (it doesn't return a card_id does it ?)...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you're right of course, updated.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why I haven't thought of this... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could use a decorator to remove some of that repetitive boiler plate.

```
from functools import wraps

def replace_keyerror(func):
    """Catches KeyError and replaces it with ValueError"""

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")
    return inner
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
@replace_keyerror
def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
"""Aligns the card to the given position."""
    card = self._cards[card_ID]
    card.align(horizontal, vertical)

@replace_keyerror
def invert(self, card_ID):
    """Inverts the card's colour"""
    self._cards[card_ID].invert()
```

Comment: While it's a perfectly valid answer (and a nice-to-know feature for python newcomers) for the OP's use case I'd rather use Daniel Roseman's much more obvious solution...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Agreed in both statement. I am glad to get decorators know, and any other cases I would accept this answer. I choose Daniel Rosemann's now because that's what I going to actually implememt, but I like this more.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a decorator function to get what you want. [This link](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) is an excellent tutorial to learn what decorators are and how to use them. I'll give an example solution using decorators in your case.

Basically, you just create a function that takes a function as a parameter and returns the wrapper that does something special with it. One that might fit your solution would look like this:

```
def catch_invalid_card_exception(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):    
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid card ID") # Not "invaild" ;)
    return wrapper
```

...then you can decorate your functions/methods like this:

```
@catch_invalid_card_exception
def shift(self, card_ID, amount):
    """Moves the card by the given amount of pixels.
        :param amount: the horizontal and vertical amount of shifting in pixels; tuple"""
    self._cards[card_ID].shift(amount)

@catch_invalid_card_exception
def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
    """Aligns the card to the given position."""
    card = self._cards[card_ID]
    card.align(horizontal, vertical)

@catch_invalid_card_exception
def invert(self, card_ID):
    """Inverts the card's colour"""
    self._cards[card_ID].invert()
```

...which is really just syntactic sugar for this:

```
def shift(self, card_ID, amount):
    # ...
shift = catch_invalid_card_exception(shift)

def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
    # ...
align = catch_invalid_card_exception(align)

def invert(self, card_ID):
    # ...
invert = catch_invalid_card_exception(invert)
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and the explanation, they helped a lot.

Comment: @Neinstein: If it helped, don't forget to upvote it or mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider making your cards collection into your own type of collection that can provide the customized exceptions you require. If you are using a `dict` for your cards collection, you might make your own `dict` with custom behavior like this:

```
class CardsCollection(dict):
    '''A dict-like collection of cards'''
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            # first try default behavior
            super().__self__(key)
        except KeyError:
            # it didn't work! 
            raise ValueError("Invalid card ID: {!r}".format(key))
```

Now you can just do your various methods like this:

```
    def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
        """Aligns the card to the given position."""
            card = self._cards[card_ID]
            card.align(horizontal, vertical)
etc. etc.
```

...just make sure to use your class for your `._cards` attribute.

```
_cards = CardsCollection(card1_ID = card1, card2_ID = card2)
```

OR:

```
_cards = CardsCollection({'card1_ID': card1, 'card2_ID': card2})
```

The nice thing about this is that your UI class is not committed to some kind of customized or unusual interface (i.e., `getcard()`) for the object holding the data. The interface here is consistent with the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Therefore, if for some reason you decide that you would like to use the same UI for another object class, you have used a tried-and-true API that will translate across just about anything that has been written in a way consistent with the Python data model.